# Method overloading including parent and child class

Tags: java, object, java-7, overloading

Why does the following code print `"string"`? Why is there no error because the method call is ambiguous?

```
class Mixer {
    void print(String s) {
        System.out.println("string");
    }

    void print(Object o) {
        System.out.println("object");
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Mixer m = new Mixer();
        m.print(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Object class is parent class of String Class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation

The `String`-method is chosen because it is the **most specific** of those types.

Since both methods would be *accessible* and *applicable* Java selects the **most specific** of both, this is described in the **Java Language Specification** in detail.

See [JLS§15.12.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2) which says:

> There may be more than one such method, in which case the *most specific* one is chosen. The descriptor (signature plus return type) of the most specific method is one used at run time to perform the method dispatch.

[JLS§15.12.2.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5) lists all rules that are used to determine the *most specific* method.

---

### Example

Take a look at the following methods:

```
public void foo(Object o) { ... }
public void foo(AbstractCollection<String> o) { ... }
public void foo(AbstractList<String> o) { ... }
public void foo(ArrayList<String> o) { ... }
```

With each method the specified type gets **more specific**, if you give an `ArrayList` or `null` it will thus first use the lowest method.